# Two regression lines in one plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, pearson-correlation

I have two `cor.test` results. I would like to visualize this in a plot using `geom_smooth`. So far, I have a working code with one regression line, but I don't know how to add a second regression line to the same plot. This is my code so far:

```
cor(opg6wave1$godimportant, opg6wave1$aj, use = 'complete.obs')#-0.309117
cor(opg6wave6$godimportant, opg6wave6$aj, use = 'complete.obs') ##=-0.4321519

ggplot(opg6wave1, aes(x= godimportant, y= aj))+ 
geom_smooth()+ 
labs(title = "Religion og abort over tid", x='Religiøsitet', y= 'Holdning til abort')+
theme_classic()
```

Thank y'all:)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to your dataset, you might want to share it? I'm using the `diamonds` dataset from tidyverse. By putting the dataset in the `ggplot(...)` command you then have it transfer to any underlying `geom_...`. You want to specify the data for each regression line separately. We can have two `geom_smooth()` by specifying the data for each of them separately.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot()+ 
  geom_smooth(diamonds %>% filter(color=="E"), 
              mapping=aes(x=depth, y=price))+
  geom_smooth(diamonds %>% filter(color=="J"), 
              mapping=aes(x=depth, y=price)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

The above for linear model smooth:

```
ggplot()+ 
  geom_smooth(diamonds %>% filter(color=="E"), 
              mapping=aes(x=depth, y=price),
              method=lm)+
  geom_smooth(diamonds %>% filter(color=="J"), 
              mapping=aes(x=depth, y=price),
              method=lm) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]